# Adding a Navigation Controller to an existing project

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I'm sure this is something stupid (it nearly always is when I finally decide to post :) but I can't seem to figure it out, so here goes:

I have a project which contains a UITableViewController (among others) which works fine, but I decided I wanted to enable editing on it and that means it needs to be contained within a UINavigationController.  So I added one to the project, set it up so the view is loaded from my table view controller nib, and... it comes up empty. Just a white view with the blue nav controller bar up top.

I've verified that the table view is getting loaded - viewDidLoad runs, at least.  Clearly something's not hooked up, probably something in IB, but I just can't seem to see it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you creating the navigation controller?  It sounds like you may not have the root controller set up in it

Comment: I have no idea where to start. Try searching on Youtube - "Navigation Controller & UITableView tutorial"

Comment: Yes you should go with slev, you need to set up the root viewController first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.h class

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

In your AppDelegate.m class

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:      
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{ 
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]   
    initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
}
```

Try this. It may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class inheritance from UITableViewController to uiviewcontroller. In the xib put the table view and attach it with an iboutlet for uitableview, set the two required protocols for table view and hope that is done if I am not missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forget to pass nib name in the interface builder. Try selecting viewControler inside UINavigation Controller in interface builder and set the nib name and class there. If you by-mistake set the nib name and class name on UINavigation controller remove the nib name and class from there.

Answer (score 0):

Its to use the navigation bar rather than using navigation controller since it can fulfill your requirements.

Just place the navigation bar in Xib file & add an action button event over the button.